# Use Condition in Computed Field with Field Collections

Tags: 7, entities

I have an entity with a field colleciton (fc_details), and in that field collection I have fields amount(field_amount) and Type (field_type)

There are several examples to sum up field colleciton values in computed field like:

```
$sum = 0;
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
  foreach($wrapper->field_fc_details as $collection) {
    $sum += $collection->field_amount->value();
  }

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $sum;
```

But I want to sum up values, where field_type values = "Z".

I tried variations of "if($wrapper->field_type->value()='Z' " inside foreach, but then site gives 500 error.

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and let me know how you go.

```
if($collection->field_type->value() == 'Z') {
  $sum += $collection->field_amount->value();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried this and this throws 500 error and "Undefined variable: colletion.." error as well.

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache? Also can you please add what's in your error log.

Comment: Cache cleared. with $wrapper trial, I only get 500 Error. There is no additional error in log. While trying with $collection, it gives 500 error + undefined variable for collection + Trying to get property of non-object error.

Comment: can you do a print_r of collection object and see what variables are available?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved the problem by this way:
When I try to fetch the value inside the if condition, it throws 500 error. So I first assigned a variable to the control value and used it in if condition, it worked.

```
$sum = 0;
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
  foreach($wrapper->field_fc_details as $collection) {
   $type = $collection->field_type->value();
   if ($type == 'Z'){  
    $sum += $collection->field_amount->value();
   }
  }
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $sum;
```

Still couldn't get the reason, but it works.